# Is “verb+こと+数量” a fixed pattern?

Tags: clause-pattern

琴里がいるのは、士道たちのいる天宮アリーナから縦方向に距離を**隔てること一万五〇〇〇メートル**、夜闇の中に浮遊する空中艦<フラクシナス>の艦橋だった。

Hi. What is the function of the こと here? I have never seen the construction “verb+こと+数量”. Is it a fixed pattern?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a fixed and rather bookish expression. It originated from [漢文訓読](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanbun) tradition, a translation method to read Chinese text word-by-word in Japanese. Japanese needs all elements before the main verb, but Chinese put some [adjuncts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)) after the verb and the object, like English. In this case, it is customary to parse it as if the verb is an outer subject to the adjunct.

> 不絶如縷 "as protracted as a thread" → 絶えざること縷のごとし
> 処門下三年 "be a follower for three years" → 門下に処ること三年
> 君美甚 "you are handsome, very much" → 君の美しきこと甚だし

This becomes a fixed pattern to focus on the adverbial element, emphasizing how much the degree or amount is, not limited to numbers.

> 感動すること[しきり](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%A0%BB%E3%82%8A)だった "deeply I was grateful"
> 心強いこと[この上ない](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) "more than ever it is reassuring"
> 世話になったこと数知れず "countless times one owes to somebody"
> 悪戦苦闘すること半日 "a half day of hard struggle"

Note that the style itself is a part of idiom, so no particle follows こと.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, could you translate the three expressions? And which part is the adverbial element?
感動することしきりだった
心強いこと限りない
世話になったこと数知れず

Comment: @chinoalpha Edited, improved a bit.